why does my modal not close when I click outside the modal?
I have a webpage with an image. When I click on the image, it opens modal. When I click on the close button, it closes the modal. However, when I click outside the modal, it doesn't close the modal. I added event listener to detect clicks but doesn't work. I am out of ideas. Here is my code. Thanks.


document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var modal       = document.getElementById("imageModal");
  var modalImg    = document.getElementById("modalImage");
  var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");

  // Select only images with the 'modal-trigger' class
  var images = document.querySelectorAll(".modal-trigger");

  images.forEach(function(img) {
    img.onclick = function() {
      modal.style.display = "block";
      var modalSrc = this.getAttribute("data-modal-src") || this.src;
      modalImg.src = modalSrc;
      captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
    }
  });

  var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

  // Check if the close button exists
  if (span) {
    span.onclick = function() {
      modal.style.display = "none";
    }
  } else {
    console.error("Close button not found.");
  }

  // Close the modal if the user clicks anywhere outside the modal content
  window.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    // Check if the click is outside the modal content
    if (event.target === modal) {
      modal.style.display = "none";
    }
  });
});
/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: none;       /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed;     /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1;          /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 20px;   /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;      /* Full width */
  height: 100%;     /* Full height */
  overflow: auto;   /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

/* Modal Content (image) */
.modal-content {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 60%;
}

/* Caption of Modal Image (Image Text) - Add some padding */
#caption {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 700px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ccc;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

/* Add Animation - Zoom in the Modal */
.modal-content,
#caption {
  animation-name: zoom;
  animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

@keyframes zoom {
  from { transform: scale(0) }
   to  { transform: scale(1) }
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 35px;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #bbb;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.timeline-item img {
  display: block;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease, transform 0.3s ease;
  cursor: pointer; /* Show a pointer cursor on hover */
}

.timeline-item img:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
  transform: scale(1.05); /* Slightly enlarge the image on hover */
}
<div class="timeline-item" style=" left: 120px;">
  <img alt="" class="modal-trigger" 
       src="https://compote.slate.com/images/22ce4663-4205-4345-8489-bc914da1f272.jpeg?crop=1560%2C1040%2Cx0%2Cy0&width=1280" 
       style=" position: relative; top: 70px; width: 215px; left: -30px;" 
  />
</div>

<div id="imageModal" class="modal">
  <em>
    <span class="close">×</span> 
    <img alt="" class="modal-content" id="modalImage" />
  </em>
  <div id="caption"></div>
</div>

</div>




You added the event listener to the modal. So how will it detect clicks outside the modal?

Sorry, I just updated my code. It still doesn't work.

You need to add the event listener to the elements being clicked on. One way to accomplish this is to have an element that covers the screen and contains your modal as its parentNode -and put the event listener on that.

Isn't if (event.target === modal) backwards? You want to detect clicks on something other than the modal.

HTML5 offers a modal system using the <dialog> tag with the js .showModal() method in which you can still use Boostrap CSS. Simpler and more reliable to use than B5's JS/CSS machinery. (and use CSS ::backdrop )
